# The use of && in C

Tags: c, ampersand

I am pretty new to C, I used the search function but I didn't have any luck finding the legality and the use of && in C.

The question that this arises from is quite vague and some insight would be great!

Is the expression on the second line legal? Why or why not? What does it mean?

```
int x;
... &&x ...
```

From what I have been able to come up with and search around for was that this is a legal statement and it gets the address of the label x , although to me this does not seem like the correct representation.

Comment: The && is the logical 'and' operator in C. Are you perhaps referring to the single & ?

Comment: Please post the code correctly, to post inline code use backticks ``'`'`` and to post blocks of code just indent them with 4 spaces.

Comment: It depends on what `...` and `...` are. Please show complete statements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a basic operator in the language that can be found in any text book and a lot of web sites.

Comment: @JonathanWood This is the whole question sadly.
and Andrew Fan, no this is how the question is presented.

Comment: & has three meanings in C: Unary adress operator `&x`, binary bitwise AND operator `a & b` and binary logical operator `x && y`. Learn all 3 and you may understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be legal, but not in the way you're thinking.

- `&&` is the "logical and" operator.  It *could* be legal in your example depending on what's in the `...`.
- As a unary "address of" operator it's not legal, since `&x` will be an "rvalue" and not define storage.  Therefore, a second `&` will not be allowed.